# How do I select row which has a max value in other column - PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm just starting with PostgreSQL and I bet there is a simple answer for my qs.

I have a view like:

```
 county - candidate - votes
Abbeville - John Kasich - 157
Abbeville - Ben Carson - 305
Abbeville - Ted Cruz - 876
Abbeville - Jeb Bush - 236
Abbeville - Hillary Clinton - 1501
Abbeville - Marco Rubio - 740
Abbeville - Bernie Sanders - 312
Abbeville - Donald Trump - 1353
Abbot - Hillary Clinton - 0
Abbot - Bernie Sanders - 1
Abington - Ben Carson - 53
Abington - John Kasich - 299
Abington - Bernie Sanders - 1352
```

And I would like to write a query which returns who has most votes per county like:

```
    county - candidate - votes
    Abbeville - Hillary Clinton - 1501
    Abbot - Bernie Sanders - 1 
    Abington - Bernie Sanders - 1352
```

I tried this query but cannot return right candidate:

```
select
distinct on (county) county , candidate ,max(votes) over(partition by county)
from primary_results_csv prc 
group by county, candidate, votes
order by county
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but you don't need the `group by` or the `max(votes)` window function when using `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on (county) *
from primary_results_csv
order by county, votes desc;
```

The equivalent solution using window functions would be:

```
select county, candidate, votes
from (
   select *, max(votes) over (partition by county) as max_votes
   from primary_results_csv
) t
where votes = max_votes;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fa2cb81b9efe4502cf6af54941ce43de)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I used the equivalent solution and it was a perfect match to what I needed. So it's solved :)

Comment: @Grzegorz-so - you might (unlikely though it may be) to be careful of a situation where a draw occurs - the result is non-deterministic using the SQL above - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=91a602841c86118d9b96c48d40b4f64b). It would be entirely unfair to give a candidate victory on the basis that they were inserted into a database first - presumably arbitrary? It's also worth nothing that the window function version of the query which **does** pull out ties.